# How to create a pipeline in azure devops to deploy scripts

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hello everyone I'm trying to automate the process to deploy our script but I'm new in azure devops and I don't know where to start.

I want to create a pipeline that everytime new code its pushed to the master branch it will be automatically deploy to the destination server.

here an example:

[image]

we have an instance of azure devops running in one of our servers (server1), this is where our script repo are, once the code its merged in the master branch the pipeline should deploy the script to e:\scripts in server2.

the repository only contains powershell script and just need to move the files from the repo the destination server.

these servers are windows and the azure devops version its Dev17.M153.5

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to copy files onto a target machine.

Start with a pipeline that is triggered when the file paths in the repository change:

```
- trigger:
    branches:
      include:
        - develop
    paths:
      include:
        - the/nameof/thefolder/withyour/scripts
```

Next, you'll need to specify which build agent you want to use. The build-agent is responsible for running the pipeline and it can be on the same machine as your Azure DevOps Server, but not always. Check out "Settings" (bottom-left) -> "Pipelines > Agent Pools" to get the name of your pool.

```
- pool: 
   name: 'Our Build Agents'
```

Next, the build agent will need to be able to talk to the machine. There are several factors to consider:

- **Network**: Make sure you don't have any firewall rules between your build agent and the target machine.
- **Permissions**: Make sure you have the correct permissions to write files to the remote machine. Ideally, the user account your build agent uses should be an administrator of the target machine.

There are several options on how to copy files, but the easiest is the build in [CopyFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task.

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/the/nameof/thefolder/withyour/scripts
    targetFolder: \\MACHINENAME\$E\Scripts
```

Other options:

- running a PowerShell/bash script to copy the items
- rsync, robocopy,etc